# Very odd behavior with saving a view inside of a list adapter and trying to access it later

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, android-progressbar

I have a listadapter as an inner class of my activity. Inside of the getView() I inflate a layout file which has a few different views inside of it. I save one of those views (a progress bar) to a

```
Map<String,ProgressBar> progBars
```

which is defined in my activity. Later I want to update the progress bar when I click a button. So I find the progress bar,

```
ProgressBar pb = progBars.get("key");
```

Now I specifically check

```
if(pb!=null)
```

and it is NOT null. I try to set the progress on it and nothing changes. BUT if I go to a new activity and then come back OR if I go back to the previous activity (back button) and then return to this one and I click the button the progress bar correctly updates to the value. This makes absolutely no sense to me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT try to cache views used by `ListAdapter`s. `ListView`, `GridView`, and other `AdapterView`s automatically recycle views that get scrolled off screen.

Please watch this video: [The World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with not caching views in listadapter. In this code I am only saving the progress bars of the first 5 or so rows. Any other thoughts on how to accomplish this instead? This also doesn't explain why it does work when I leave the activity and come back...